# CMake compile from source vs find_package

Tags: android, c++, cmake

Let's assume I have a shared library A and a shared library B. I have sources for both and both are  CMake-aware. A is vendor-provided and B is mine.

#### Case 1: Install and build on Windows

I can install A on the system and use find_package(A) in B/CMakeLists.txt.
Works fine.

#### Case 2: Build from source for another platform, but from Windows

I want to recompile everything from source for some other ABI (use case: I want to recompile the library A and B for Android). Now a call to include(B/CMakeLists.txt) would make more sense so that I can pick up the source and compile it using Android Studio.

However A/CMakeLists.txt contains now a call to find_package(B), which breaks the CMake build.

So I guess my question here is "What did I miss in a typical CMake workflow ?".

I know I can use flags and conditions for MSVC and Android, but I have the feeling I'm missing the bigger picture.

Comment: "*Now a call to include(B/CMakeLists.txt) would make more sense*"... Why do the dependencies change for Case 2? Case 1 indicates that library B depends on library A. So, Case 2 should be the same. Why couldn't you build A using Android Studio, then build B separately afterwards using `find_package(A)` as you did in Case 1?

Comment: Right. I guess that would be doable. My approach was to have all the code of all libraries in the same android studio project and compile them all from the same project. But I guess you're right, I could build the libraries independently and link them in the same way as Case 1.